# Shorthand promise chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to teach myself node and express and trying to build a simple login script. I am new to Javascript promises.

My user Model has functions like `exists`, `verifiyPassword`, and `isApproved`. Each function looks like this:

```
//Simplified verifyPassword function
User.prototype.verifyPassword=function(suppliedPassword){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(suppliedPassword === this.password){
            return resolve(true);
        }
        return reject(new Error('Password incorrect'));
    })
}
```

I want to chain a series of these methods together like so (note: I am testing using the **WRONG** password)

1st try:

```
 user.exists()
.then(user.verifyPassword(req.body.password)).
.then(user.isApproved())
.then(()=>{
     console.log("Login successful");
}).catch(err=>{
      console.log("ERROR", err);
      throw err
});
```

Result: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Password incorrect
Login successful`

Obviously the wrong result (error wasn't caught and still made a successful login). I believe this is because `user.verifyPassword()` is not returning its promise.

2nd try:

```
 user.exists()
.then(user.verifyPassword.bind(req.body.password)).
.then(user.isApproved)
.then(()=>{
     console.log("Login successful");
})
```

I think this might have worked but it did not pass `req.body.password` to `verifyPassword` (instead it passed `true`, the result of the `user.exists()` resolve).

3rd try:

```
 user.exists()
.then(()=>{return user.verifyPassword.bind(req.body.password)}).
.then(()=>{return user.isApproved})
.then(()=>{
     console.log("Login successful");
})
```

**This code works** as expected but feels terribly verbose. Is there a way I can clean this up? I am not very familiar with the ES6 shorthand tricks yet.

Comment: If `verifyPassword` does nothing asynchronous, it should not return a promise!

Comment: Your first try does not work because you are passing promises to `then` as arguments, not *functions*. `then` requires a callback - don't call the functions right away.

Comment: Are you sure the third code even works? You `.bind()` the function instead of calling it. Same for `user.isApproved`.

Comment: If you want really concise promise code, use `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: @Bergi is correct. The third snippet is almost certainly not doing what you expect or believe. It will indeed print "Login successful" to the console log, but it will not have actually called `verifyPassword` or `isApproved`.

Comment: user.exists()
.then(user.verifyPassword(req.body.password)). -> You executed user.verifyPassword right immediately, that's the problem. Instead, create new anonymous function and execute user.verifyPassword and return.

Comment: I think this question is reasonable, why it's down voted?

Answer (score 1):

sure you can shorten your code but first of all there are a few misconceptions about promises. In the end I'm giving you a solution and another short version. But I would recommend you to really try and understand promises in detail before just using that code. It's an important part of javascript.

https://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/

https://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

---

### 1. Try

```
.then(user.verifyPassword(req.body.password))
```

*then* is supposed to take a function. But you're passing the **result** of verifyPassword which is the Promise object. Your expression becomes `then(null)` so that the previous result of `user.exists()` passes through.

Instead you can do the following:

```
user.exists()
.then(() => user.verifyPassword(req.body.password))
```

---

### 2. Try

> Obviously the wrong result (error wasn't caught and still made a
>   successful login). I believe this is because user.verifyPassword() is
>   not returning its promise.

Have a look at the function signature of [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

`function.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])``

So, you're passing *req.body.password* as thisArg. It's being ignored because user got initiated with new. **But** now there's no *arg1*, so *suppliedPassword* is undefined.

Instead you would do:

```
user.verifyPassword.bind(null, req.body.password)
```

---

### 3. Try

You're not calling verifyPassword and isApproved here. So, try it like that:

```
.then(()=>{return user.isApproved()})
```

or even shorter:

```
.then( () => user.isApproved() )
```

---

**Solution**

```
 user.exists()
  .then(() => user.verifyPassword(req.body.password))
  .then(user.isApproved)
  .then(()=>{
     console.log("Login successful");
  }).catch(err=>{
      console.log("ERROR", err);
      throw err
  });
```

---

**Shorter Solution**

If you want to make us of an even shorter syntax you can use async/await. [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=568g8hxJJp4) might help you.

```
async () => {
  try {
    await user.exists();
    await user.verifyPassword(req.body.password);
    await user.isApproved();

    console.log("Login successful");
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR", err);
    throw err
  }
```

Comment: Great answer. Note that if you can't use Async & Await but supports ES6 generator, you can use "co" module to do similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await like this:

```
const checkUser = async () => {        
    await user.exists();
    await user.verifyPassword();
    await user.isApproved();
    console.log("Login successful");        
}
```